# Windows 8.1 0x80070522 error on secondary drive

Tags: windows-8, permissions, windows-8.1

I need urgent help somehow suddenly something changed permissions and maybe ownership on my secondary drive and right now I can't save or copy anything there.

I checked permissions and the Authenticated User had no rights so I changed it back to the right permissions. But it didn't solved the problem.
Than I looked up the Owner an the owner is TrustedInstaller, I don't know if that's right or not because after updating to Windows 8.1 my MBR ended up on this drive and half of my installed softwares are there too and maybe windows set the owner to Trustedinstaller.

How can I resolve this without damaging the MBR and my softwares.

Oh and I'm the admin user and UAC is turned off.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling UAC as suggested by some answers is not the way to go.

If you see the 0x80070522 error, you first have to check NTFS permissions and ensure you have write permission. You can do this either via the GUI (right click > Properties > Security tab) or by using command line shell with `takeown` and `icacls` as shown [there](https://superuser.com/questions/428163/how-to-delete-the-windows-directory-from-an-old-hard-drive/1087643#1087643).

Then, you also have to check the **NTFS integrity level**. Windows set this on some folders or for example on the system volume to prevent users from creating files at the volume root (that's what is responsible for the 0x80070522 error). The integrity level can take different values from *High* to *Low*. If you encounter 0x80070522 error, chances are that the integrity level is set to High. To fix that, you just have to pull it down back to *Medium* that way :

```
icacls D:\ /setintegritylevel M
```

(replace `D:\` with your target path, execute as Administrator)

Comment: After days of experimenting with `takeown` and `icacls` without success, I finally found your answer, and `icacls D:\ /setintegritylevel M` was the solution for me!!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: this command can run for 10+ minutes without any output. Don't kill it too early :)

Answer (score 0):

**Only on your second hard drive**

Right below **Owner**
Click the **Edit** button

[X] Replace ownership on sub folders and files.

It should show you username.
Click on that

Click OK and wait a long time

Comment: Didn't work for me, the only thing what happend after this that I got an error which says that the Trash is damaged on drive would you like to empty it :) than I found an MS TN forum post which suggested to disable admin aproval mode in local policies and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start > Run > SECPOL.MSC.
2. Once the “Local Security Policy” window opens, under “Security Settings” > Local Policies > Security Options.
3. Scroll down to find “User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode” and then disable it. Yes -> disable it. Then, click the OK button.
4. Restart your computer.